# Why pictures out of selection area?

Tags: canvas, angular6, fabricjs

I have little problem about selections of images in fabricJS.
More of images are selected right( in the selection area), but also some images out of selection area. With then it  can be related and how to fix it?

[image]

```js
public openSvgImage(url): Promise<Image> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, (objects, options) => {
            const svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            this.addAndPositionSVG(svg, 'svg');
        });
    })
}

private addAndPositionSVG(svg: FObject, name: string = 'shape') {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        svg.name = name;
        this.fabric().add(svg);
        this.fabric().setActiveObject(svg);
        svg.scaleToWidth(this.fabric().getWidth() / 4);
        svg.scaleToHeight(this.fabric().getHeight() / 4);
        svg.viewportCenter();
        svg.setCoords();
        this.render();
        this.addPixabayResolve && this.addPixabayResolve();
    });
}
```

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/h06rojc4/). Can you update it, stating your issue?

Comment: Ok, but when I try this path https://pixabay.com/get/ec32b70e2cf41c3e815b4405e74e4194e16ae3d01db6134995f8c27e.svg 
It's not show correctly.I think it's not correctly image svg.